# Scala: Multiple type parameters for implicit class

Tags: scala, implicit, generic-programming

I'm trying to port parts of a Haskell library for datatype-generic programming to Scala. Here's the problem I've run into:

I've defined a trait, `Generic`, with some container-type parameter:

```
trait Generic[G[_]] {
     // Some function declarations go here
 }
```

Now I have an abstract class, `Collect`, with three type parameters, and a function declaration (it signifies a type than can collect all subvalues of type `B` into a container of type `F[_]` from some structure of type `A`):

```
abstract class Collect[F[_],B,A] {
  def collect_ : A => F[B]
}
```

In order to make it extend Generic, the first two type parameters `F[_]` and `B` are given, and `A` is curried (this effect is simulated using type lambdas):

```
class CollectC[F[_],B] extends Generic[({type C[A] = Collect[F,B,A]})#C] {
    // Function definitions go here
}
```

The problem is that I need the last class definition to be implicit, because later on in my code I will need to be able to write functions like

```
class GUnit[G[_]](implicit gg: Generic[G]) {
    // Some definitions
}
```

When I simply prepend `implicit` to the class definition, I get the an error saying `implicit classes must accept exactly one primary constructor parameter`. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there a known way to work around it? I don't currently see how I could refactor my code while keeping the same functionality, so any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit classes don't work that way. They are a shorthand for implicit *conversions*. For instance `implicit class Foo(i: Int)` is equal to `class Foo(i: Int); implicit def Foo(i: Int) = new Foo(i)`. So it only works with classes that have exactly one parameter in their constructor. It would not make sense for most 0 parameter (type-)classes.

The title of your question also seems to suggest that you think the compilation error is talking about type parameters of the type constructor, but I hope the above paragraph also makes clear that it is actually talking about *value* parameters of the *value* constructor.

For what (I think) you are trying to do, you will have to provide an implicit instance of `CollectC` yourself. I suggest putting it in the companion object of `Collect`. But you can choose an [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/1374461) if that fits your needs better.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Generic[G[_]] {
  // Some function declarations go here
}

abstract class Collect[F[_],B,A] {
  def collect_ : A => F[B]
}

object Collect {
  implicit def mkCollectC[F[_],B]: CollectC[F,B] = new CollectC[F,B]
}

class CollectC[F[_],B] extends Generic[({type C[A] = Collect[F,B,A]})#C] {
  // Function definitions go here
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there were four feature warnings; for details, enable `:setting -feature' or `:replay -feature'
defined trait Generic
defined class Collect
defined object Collect
defined class CollectC

scala> implicitly[Generic[({type C[X] = Collect[List,Int,X]})#C]]
res0: Generic[[X]Collect[[+A]List[A],Int,X]] = CollectC@12e8fb82
```